# Feature importance interpretation in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, binary-data, importance

I am using the feature importance of logistic regression to rank the most influential features. My problem lies that I do not how to exactly interpret the results of the feature importance. I know that positive and negative values push the classifier towards the positive and negative class respectively. If I get a positive value equal to 2, I do not know what that exactly means. Does the influence logistic or linear and how much is the influence numerically?

Comment: When you say "feature importance" are you referring to the coefficients or something else?

Comment: i refer to the magnitudes of the coefficients

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ranking features in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195550/ranking-features-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106344/how-to-quantify-the-relative-variable-importance-in-logistic-regression-in-terms may help.

Comment: This book covers different feature importance methods [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/). Model agnostic ones could be helpful here. Magnitude of the coefficients may not be sufficient for reliable ranking.